# Slow boot after CMOS reset

Tags: windows-7, boot, memory

I was trying to install new RAM on an old PC (Windows 7; EMX MCP61M2-icafe Motherboard) and I thought I should reset the CMOS battery to get it working. Since then the boot up process became extremely slow that I haven't gotten past the "Starting Windows" screen since.

I can access the BIOS settings and I have tried disabling and re-enabling quick boot and full screen logo. Of course it did not help. Is there a fix to this? What could be causing this problem?

The old RAM is a Transcend 1GB DDR2 533 DIMM CL4

**EDIT**: I checked the memory clock setting, and it is set to 'auto'. It says 266 MHz. I tried increasing the setting but it just reverts back to the default value.

**UPDATE**: Forget it, pc starts normally now. My solution was to wait out the entire boot up process which initially took more than an hour before the desktop environment finally showed up. Reboots after that went normally. Man that was fun.

Comment: Have you tried reverting to the old RAM to verify that the new configuration is not at fault?

Comment: Yes. The new RAM doesn't even seem to work

Comment: Did you set the clock in the bios after you reset it?

Comment: If you mean time and date, yes.

Answer (score 0):

As per OP's edit the issue has been solved, but here's a hote for future reference:

**This can be caused by switching SATA controller from IDE to AHCI mode or the other way.**

If you encounter this issue, try toggling that feature in BIOS/UEFI setup (check manual if you can't find it).